# Angular dynamic Priority level for http request

Tags: angularjs, http

I am in following situation . Kindly help on this

I will project an http API call in angular with lower priority. I have enabled the http cache so that I dont want my webservice to be hit again.

So Now if user request for that lower priority API Call data then suddenly I have to increase it to top priority. Since I have enabled the cache hence I cant project another one.

As far as I reviewed there was no any way to change the priority of the projected http API Calls .

```
$http.get("localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/";,{priority:20}‌​).then(function(response) { $scope.myWelcome = $scope.myWelcome + response.data ; console.log(response.data); });
```

Kindly help on this

I have tested this by projecting some API calls on initial load of the page and then on click of an Button event I just hit an one of the API call of Initial load with lower priority with high prority .

But I could not see the output which i am expecting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ANGULAR PRIORITY LEVEL CHANGING](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896738/angular-priority-level-changing)

Comment: Are you familiar with the definition of insanity attributed to Einstein?

Comment: I dont know what do you mean ? Can you elaborate me ?

Comment: *"Insanity: doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results."* Your edit didn't help much - what were you expecting? What did you try? What did you get instead? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: $http.get("http://localhost:65291/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld"+20+"?test=hari",{priority:20})
  .then(function(response) {
   
       $scope.myWelcome =    $scope.myWelcome + response.data ; 
     console.log(response.data);
}); Now my code will call an API with priority 20 then I will call the same api with priority 1 . Since I have enabled the cache i was not able to call my api and get it with top priority

Comment: Oh, for pity's... **[edit] the question**.

Comment: I have updated my previous comment . Please see it

Comment: My question looks good, straightforward and pretty elaborate. Doesn't makes sense ?

Comment: I don't want you to update your comment. I want you, as I specifically asked, to edit the question to include a MCVE of what you've tried and the problem with it you're trying to solve. No, your question is not good. What you are showing is a (syntactically invalid) requirement, not an attempt at implementation, and this isn't a code-writing service or a tutorial. Read the material in the [help] and improve it, or just delete it. If you mean that you need to pass additional parameters as part of the request (either header, URL or body) then read the angular http docs.